# Various Bluetooth HC-06 modules erratic in different ways

Tags: bluetooth, hc-06

I am trying to make a Bluetooth controlled robot and have troubles with the Bluetooth modules. I used  3 HC-06 Bluetooth module. All of them have different problems.

- I could not find the 1st HC-06 under the list of Bluetooth devices in the settings.
- The 2nd HC-06 could be paired with the phone but I could not send the message on the Bluetooth terminal app (The error message from the app is below).
- The 3rd HC-06 could be paired and I could send a message but the message was not registered on the Arduino nor on serial monitor. On the Bluetooth terminal app, the message was received but not replied.

What could be the problem? I'm pretty sure my connections are correct as I have checked them and they used to work.

[image: This is the error on the second HC-06]

Comment: Check your power supply for the BT module. Try 1000uF or more decoupling close to the module.

Comment: why would putting capacitors around the bluetooth help, is it also subject to EMI?